# WCF 4.5 Versioning

Tags: .net, wcf, c#-4.0, versioning

I have a WCF service with a data contract and etc...

I need to make some changes in the contract, because some customers I had to change the business logic and add two data members in the data contract. The catch is, the Java client is breaking, even with `IsRequired = false`, only he don't accept this change, clients in PHP, Ruby and Python accepts the change.

How can I solve this? There's some way to fix this on .NET side or another way to version the service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly, You are adding 2 `DataMember`s for existing `DataContract`. It should not be any issue unless unless you have Modify/removed some existing `DataMember`s

```
1. Add new Non-Required Members [IsRequired = false] --- Client unaffected & Missing values are inirialised to defaults.
```

Comment: Yes. But I have a Java client integrated with this web service who is complain about broken contract.

Comment: I am thinking.. It should work Renan!. Can you please post your sample code if possible.

Comment: For some reason, the proxy in Java client needed to be updated manually.